# What happens when premium subscription expires on TradingView?

Tags: tradingview-api

I am fairly new at TradingView and I have tried to find the answer to my question by writing to TradingView and asking the internal community. TradingView didn't respond to my question and the two who responded to my question in the internal community couldn't help me either.

So the scenario is this:
I have a premium subscription and I have posted some invite-only scripts where I have users invited to use it.

And the question is this:

What would happen if my subscription expires?
Will all the invited be able to see the source code of my script?
Since the posts/ideas are never deleted I would assume that the source code will be available there as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing happens. You will lose all your premium privileges but you get to keep whatever work you have published as it is.

The indicator will remain invite-only and <strike>you will still be able to give access to people</strike> but a Premium account is required to manage users of invite-only scripts. Which also means no one will see the source code because it will still be an invite-only script.

You will of course not able to publish any new invite-only indicators.

Comment: Thank you Baris! So TradingView kinda takes a snapshot of your state and source code upon publishment?

Comment: Yes, I guess you can say that.

Comment: This is correct except for the "you will still be able to give access to people" part. A Premium account is required to manage users of invite-only scripts. Note that banned Premium accounts cannot manage access to their invite-only scripts for the ban's duration.

Comment: @PineCoders-LucF yes, you are right. if my memory serves, for a period of time I was still able to grant  access some years ago, although I no longer had a Premium account. But now, unfortunately,  I no longer have a Premium account and can't give access to  my invite-only scripts to anyone indeed. Edited my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in other words---in order to play---youve got to continue to pay tradingview, you cant just use them to continue to monetize your protected code indicators w/o keeping your TV premium subscription.